# XML File as Command-Line Argument and Parse in Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse the command-line argument in Python as follows:

```
python test.py /home/Desktop/test.xml
```

I've found getopt, but how does that work with three arguments? This source only shows 4, and I don't know how to have less. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

And is DOM the most efficient way to parse XML files?

Answer (score 1):

I would forgo `getopt` in favor of [argparse](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html), which has a very good tutorial [here](http://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/argparse.html#id1). `argparse` shows nicer errors with less work. I think `getopt` is used mainly for compatibility with the C API Both modules, however, support fewer arguments. In your particular case, you will probably want to do something like the following

```
import argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage)
    help = "The file to operate on"
    parser.add_argument("infile", type=argparse.FileType('r'), help=help)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args.infile
```

Depending on your needs, [lxml](http://lxml.de/) can be very useful/powerful. I've personally used [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (for some not-so-complicated XML stuff). The recommended module in the Standard Library is [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) which has a nice API and can do a lot of XML things.

**edit**: `getopt` is *not* deprecated as I incorrectly stated before

Answer (score 0):

A single command-line argument is a simple case, no need for `getopt` or other parsing modules.
Try using the last argument as a file name for use in any XML library.

For pythonic XML handling, use [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) .

```
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'args:', sys.argv
    print 'last arg:', sys.argv[-1]
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        sys.exit()
    tree = ET.parse(sys.argv[-1])
    root = tree.getroot()
    for child in root:
        print child.tag, child.text
```

(Add file existence checks and error handling after basics are understood).

Comment: 8 lines with `argparse` gives much more useful feedback to the user and does the "file existence checks and error handling" for free. If the script grows in complexity, expanding the CLI is also much simpler. With `argv` you're saving 3 lines of code and losing these benefits